# Is there any graph database for android?

Tags: android, database, data-structures, graph

I want to store a directed weighted graph like

hello--5-->world

What are the graph databases available in android?

Comment: Yes! [neo4j](http://neo4j.com/news/neo4j-mobile-for-android-v0-1/). Get it from [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mobile-android). Use [Google](http://www.google.com) to know how to use it.

Comment: there is also: http://www.sparsity-technologies.com/

Comment: 1. move to software recommendation 2. use https://github.com/wuman/titan-android